# Ajax call issue in UIWebview in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ajax, ipad, uiwebview

I am using a `UIWebview` to load a webpage. My webpage displays some graphs & after every 5 seconds my webpage send a ajax call to server to reload the latest data in graph.This webpage working fine in android like real time graph progress.But in case of iOS webpage load is very slow a loading image appears then graph is loaded in `UIWebView`.I have tested this in safari it is working fine.Is there any solution for this?